# Swap stacking order of two divs (or any object for that matter)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Is there an easy way through pure javascript to swap the stacking order of two divs?

Suppose I have four divs:

```
<div id="div1">Div number 1</div>
<div id="div2">Div number 2</div>
<div id="div3">Div number 3</div>
<div id="div4">Div number 4</div>
```

Through (pure) javascript, I want to swap (the stacking order of) div2 and div3 so it becomes:

```
<div id="div1">Div number 1</div>
<div id="div3">Div number 3</div>
<div id="div2">Div number 2</div>
<div id="div4">Div number 4</div>
```

I can't seem to find a way to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function can be used to swap the positions of two elements:

```
function swapPositions(element1, element2) {
    var copy = element2.cloneNode(true);
    element1.parentNode.insertBefore(copy, element1);
    element2.parentNode.insertBefore(element1, element2);
    element2.parentNode.replaceChild(element2, copy);
}
```

Try it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cwj2v625/2/).